# Function not returning a boolean, returns None always

Tags: python

The following code returns `None` instead of `True`, when the input shows that it should clearly return `True`, what is the error here?

```
def checkminus(j):
    linp = []
    for a in j:
        if a == '-':
            if len(linp) > 0:
                linp = []
                return False
                quit()
            else:
                linp.append(a)
        else:
            linp.append(a)
    checklen(linp)
def checklen(k):
    l = len(k)
    print(l)
    if l>0:
        return True
    else:
        return False

print(checkminus(['-','5','5','8','2']))
```

Comment: Plz make your topic more informative, as one checking question could possibly answer it.

Comment: Try to show where exactly the problem is. Avoid phrasing like "Why isn't this working?"

Comment: @Yosi: the OP observed `None` was being returned where a boolean was expected. I think that that is enough of a problem description.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - I disagree, showing code, telling what you expect to get, and what you get, isn't suffice as a question on my opinion.If not please give me a reference that shows otherwise.

Comment: What, exactly, would you add that would let you solve the problem, then?

Comment: That isn't the relevant question, the post doesn't show a specific point/issue that he tried dealing with. The OP doesn't need to help me solve the problem we need to help him.

Answer (score 4):

You forgot to return the `checklen()` return value when you call it:

```
checklen(linp)
```

Add a `return` there:

```
return checklen(linp)
```

Note that `>` already gives you either `True` or `False`, so you can just return that directly:

```
def checklen(k):
    l = len(k)
    return l > 0
```

Another way of would be to use `bool(l)`; lists are `False` when empty, `True` otherwise.

Simplifying `checkminus()`:

```
def checkminus(j):
    linp = []
    for a in j:
        if a == '-':
            if linp:
                return False
        linp.append(a)
    return bool(linp)
```

which sounds to me as if you wanted to make sure `-` is only at the start of the list, or not present at all.

If so, this is easier:

```
def checkminus(j):
    return len(j) > 0 and '-' not in j[1:]
```

Comment: Checking `j[0] == '-'` won't give you the same thing, as the original function succeeds when `j` contains no hyphens.